# Crashlytics, Can't add new application

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

First attempt:

[image]
[image]

Loading activity not changing. Try to use steps in this link https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install, but with no success.

Do anybody know how to add app to Crashlytics? Several month ago I don't have such problem

Comment: are you getting the crashes correctly or having missing dysm in dashboard

Comment: @08442 have some problems with dsym, but it was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only after run `Product` -> `Archive` this step successfully done.

Xcode 10.1

Comment: Why minus this answer? I spend 2 days before solve problem. Tested on absolute new app. With build not works, only archive.

Comment: Can you tell me how did you resolve this? I am also facing the same.

Comment: While you see load animation "waiting for build", try to archive project. If not works, check that you property setup "Run Script Build Phase", [fabric video](https://cdn-cf.fabric.io/static_assets/discover/install/run_script_build_phase.mp4).